# How to separate the segments in segment control?

Tags: iphone

I want to separate the segments in segment control with one line means they appear as a buttons. And give the shadow color for that segments. Please give me any suggetions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve what you're looking for using a segmented control. You will have to implement a custom view with buttons on it.

You can add shadow color to almost any view by accessing its layer. There are few [`style attributes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW78) that handle shadows.

Comment: I want to show the shadow color at top of the button only.Please

Comment: Limiting to an edge will have to be handled differently. You can add a [`gradient layer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) to the layers hierarchy.

Comment: Ok.thank U sir.Send me ur mail id  to my mailid:venkatnaresh2011@gmail.com.If any doubts then i send to your mail id.Please sir